# composer script section os.dependent

Tags: windows, shell, composer-php

Is it possible to check for the current operating system?
The following cmd fails on windows, because chmod does not exist

```
{ ...
  "scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": "chmod -R 777 ../log"
  }
}
```

Is there a workaround to solve this ?
Kind regards, Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @alcohol for pointing me tothe right direction.
Simple solution:

```
"scripts": {
  "post-update-cmd": "php post-update-cmd.php"
}
```

post-update-cmd.php:

```
#!/bin/php
<?php

ini_set('register_argc_argv', 0);
if (!isset($argc) || is_null($argc)) die('CLI only');

$log_dir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'log';

if( strpos(strtolower(php_uname('s')), 'win') === false ) {
    exec("mkdir -p $log_dir && chmod -R 777 $log_dir");
} else { // Windows !
    if( !file_exists($log_dir) ) {
        exec("mkdir $log_dir");
    }
    echo "WinOS - no chmod available\n";
}

echo "Finished\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution is using PHP itself I reckon:

```
{ ...
  "scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": "php -r chmod('../log', 0777);"
  }
}
```

This requires the `php` binary to be in your PATH (or similar) on Linux/OSX/Windows.

> Ps: I can't recall for sure, but I believe path should be relative to
>   where your composer.json is, so you may have to adjust the above
>   path accordingly.

Comment: Composer has a special syntax `@php` for that. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#executing-php-scripts

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is to move post update command into the hook and perform all necessary check for operating system there.
In your composer:

```
{ ...
  "scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": "Hooks\MyHook::checkOS()"
  },
 "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Hooks": "src/"
    }
 }
```

}

Than create class that will handle your logic:

```
...
class MyHook(){

 public static function checkOS(){
  // 1 - get operating system
  // 2 - is chmod exist? execute chmod -R 777 ../log
}

}
```